# How to remove carriage returns from output of string?

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, google-maps

I am using wordpress as a CMS and trying to allow user fields to be input to populate the info windows in a Google Map script.  I am using this to select the id and pull in the content from a custom field.

It works fine unless there is any html in the custom-field which breaks the script.
I looked at htmlspcialchar and htmlentities but rather than strip everything out I would like to have it escaped so it still works and the html is intact.  Any suggestions?  I am pretty new to PHP and would really appreciate any pointers.

After a while I am still unable to find a great solution for this.  TheDeadMedic suggested I use esc_js

but that printed all of the actual html code instead of rendering it.

Thank you to nickfs as that solution was slightly better but the script still breaks if there are any carriage returns in the output, which makes this not so great for a CMS.

Something else I tried was to use the trim function.. this is where I am at now where it works as long as no \r in the output.  The $snip string, mapExcerpt field is where the returns are coming from:

```
<?php $post_id = 207; // Wordpress Post ID
$my_post = get_post($post_id);
$mapTitle  = $my_post->post_title;
$mapIMG = get_post_meta($post_id, 'mapImage', true);
$snip = get_post_meta($post_id, 'mapExcerpt', true);
$lat = get_post_meta($post_id, 'lat', true);
$long = get_post_meta($post_id, 'long', true);
$pass_to = '<div class="span-8"><div class="mapTitle">'.$mapTitle.'</div><div class="mapContent">'.$snip.'</div></div>';
$trimmed = trim($pass_to, " \r.");
?>
var point = new GLatLng('<?php echo $lat; $lat; ?>','<?php echo $long; $long; ?>');
var marker = createMarker(point,"<?php echo $mapTitle; $mapTitle; ?>", '<?php echo addslashes($trimmed); ?>');
map.addOverlay(marker);
```

Any other ideas out there on how I can pull this off?

Comment: Why would there be HTML in the custom field?

Comment: @Tom To control the layout, links, etc...

Comment: Why not just setup a custom field called 'location' where they can only input that lat/long and define a series of other custom fields for links, layout etc?

Comment: i do have that, i just didnt put that part in here because it is not a problem.  the reason this custom field has html included is because it is what appears in the info bubble that pops-up for the marker points.  I have another custom fields that is just for a styled image which works but then this one with the text is sort of a problem.  As long as there are no \r it works great but any carriage returns kill it.

Comment: I updated my question to show more of the code.. hope it makes more sense now

Answer (score 144, accepted):

I don't fully understand your exact problem, but the answer to the title of your question is quite simple:

```
$snip = str_replace('.', '', $snip); // remove dots
$snip = str_replace(' ', '', $snip); // remove spaces
$snip = str_replace("\t", '', $snip); // remove tabs
$snip = str_replace("\n", '', $snip); // remove new lines
$snip = str_replace("\r", '', $snip); // remove carriage returns
```

Or a all in one solution:

```
$snip = str_replace(array('.', ' ', "\n", "\t", "\r"), '', $snip);
```

You can also use regular expressions:

```
$snip = preg_replace('~[[:cntrl:]]~', '', $snip); // remove all control chars
$snip = preg_replace('~[.[:cntrl:]]~', '', $snip); // above + dots
$snip = preg_replace('~[.[:cntrl:][:space:]]~', '', $snip); // above + spaces
```

You'll still need to use `addslashes()` to output `$snip` inside Javascript.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you.  It was also tabs and new lines breaking it so I needed all of this.  Thanks again :)

Comment: Remove all whitespace characters with: `preg_replace('/\s/', ''. $str)`

Answer (score 11):

I always use this to get rid of pesky carriage returns:

```
$string = str_replace("\r\n", "\n", $string); // windows -> unix
$string = str_replace("\r", "\n", $string);   // remaining -> unix
```

Answer (score 6):

if you need to remove  new line symbols of all types (in utf8)

```
$dataWithoutCarrierReturn = preg_replace('/\R/', '', $inData);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're putting this into Javascript, you'll need to escape it for javascript strings. `addslashes()` should do the trick.

Comment: Great! Thanks that solved that problem.. only to discover a new one.  Now I am getting unterminated string literal for the automatic spaces and line breaks that the CMS generates.

Comment: Check my answer - use WP's PHP function `esc_js()` instead of `addslashes()`. It will sanitize quotes AND line breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Try JSON-encoding it, I always do that when I send data from PHP to Javascript. It solves most encoding issues, including newlines.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought, but it doesn't work in all cases. I'm facing that exact problem actually. I'm using an external XML data source that I import into MySQL and the XML has "unusual" newline chars that get saved in the DB. When retrieving via json_encode on client-side Angular then falls over because of the NLs. So far I found no means to filter them. Even tried to convert to ASCII to minimise the set of CTRL chars - nothing worked

Answer (score 1):

Use WP's own `esc_js()`, which will escape quotes and line breaks for JavaScript strings.

Comment: Hmmm when I tried this it spit out the actual html code rather than rendering it.  Maybe it is how I implemented it? Adding to my original post I tried this :  var marker = createMarker(point,"<?php echo $mapTitle; $mapTitle; ?>", '<?php echo esc_js($pass_to); ?>')

Comment: What you're doing appears to be OK - what's the code for the `createMarker` function?

Comment: function createMarker(point,name,html) {
        var marker = new GMarker(point,{icon:myIcon});
        var linkid = "link"+(gmarkers.length);
        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
          marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
          lastlinkid=linkid;
        });
        return marker;
      }

Answer (score 1):

This was the only thing solution that worked for me:

```
$dataWithoutCarrierReturn = preg_replace('/[\x0D]/', '', $inData);
```

Comment: Good answer! That was the only working solution for me too, used in a php script made for exporting data to a CSV file… Thanks