# line breaks showing up as \r\n in textarea

Tags: php, html

I am trying to display a data into textarea which is fetched from tables that i have submitted via another form. The issue comes up when a new line is entered.

The data getting displayed in the textarea is as

> lin1\r\nlin2

it should be like

```
lin1
lin2
```

I have tried nl2br but it does not work as expected. 
How can i make things optimized. Thanks

Comment: You can fix this with Javascript. \r and \n are not plain HTML like <br>. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863779/textarea-line-breaks-javascript

Comment: possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059091/how-to-remove-carriage-returns-from-output-of-string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope **`str_replace`** saves you.

```
<?php
$str='lin1\r\nlin2';
$str=str_replace('\r\n','<br>',$str);
echo $str;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
lin1
lin2
```

Comment: Wouldn't `text.replace` be a better solution?

Answer (score 12):

This problem can be solved using `stripcslashes()` when outputting your data.

Please note that the method above is different from `stripslashes()` which doesn't work in this case.

I tried using `nl2br` but it wasn't sufficient either.

Comment: `stripcslashes` works well when outputting data back into the textarea and `nl2br` works for regular html output. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is a common question and the most common answers are ln2br or str_replace.

However this is just creating unnecessary code.

In reality the problem is pretty much always that you have run the data through a mysql escape function before displaying it. Probably while you were in the process of saving it. Instead, escape the data for saving but display an unescaped version.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php echo str_replace('\r\n', "\r\n", $text_with_line_breaks); ?>
```

See single quotes & double quotes this is a trick.

A perfect solution for newbies.

Comment: Glade to know that it helped you.

Comment: This is the same, but in php side: $observacao = str_replace(PHP_EOL,'\r\n', $observacao);

Answer (score 1):

you overdo quote in insert/update statement

This problem in you case you can solve doing next

```
<?php
$str = 'lin1\r\nlin2';
$solved_str = str_replace(array("\\r","\\n"), array("\r","\n"), $str);

var_dump($str,$solved_str);
```

But you need to check insert/update statement on over quotation escape symbols

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using double quotes for \r\n such as "\r\n".  I've never had it work properly with single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

**For non- textarea use this function**

```
function escapeNonTextarea($string){

    $string=str_replace(array('\n','\r\n','\r'),array("<br>","<br","<br>"),$string);
    return $string;
}
```

**For text area use this function**

```
function escapeTextarea($string){

    $string=str_replace(array('\n','\r\n','\r'),array("\n","\r\n","\r"),$string);

    return $string;
}
```

call appropriate function and pass argument