# Formatting Content in PHP

Tags: php, function, string-formatting

I have to remove newlines and carriages from the given content through PHP.
Please tell me how?

```
  <p>\r\n    \r\n        \r\n            \r\n        \r\n        \r\n            \r\n            \r\n        \r\n        \r\n            \r\n            \r\n        \r\n        \r\n            \r\n            \r\n        \r\n        \r\n            \r\n            \r\n        \r\n        \r\n            \r\n            \r\n        \r\n        \r\n            \r\n            \r\n        \r\n    \r\n</p>
<table width="\&quot;100%\&quot;" class="\&quot;table-view\&quot;" cellpadding="\&quot;0\&quot;" cellspacing="\&quot;0\&quot;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="\&quot;2\&quot;" align="\&quot;left\&quot;">Specifications</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign="\&quot;top\&quot;"><strong>Frequency bands</strong></td>
            <td>\r\n
            <ul>\r\n
                <li>380 - 400 MHz</li>
                \r\n
                <li>410 - 430 MHz</li>
                \r\n
                <li>806 - 825, 851 - 870 MHz*</li>
                \r\n            </ul>
                \r\n</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="\&quot;top\&quot;"><strong>Power class</strong></td>
                <td>\r\n
                <ul>\r\n
                    <li>EN 300392-2 compliant, power class 4</li>
                    \r\n
                    <li>Receiver class A</li>
                    \r\n
                    <li>RF power control, 4 steps of 5dB</li>
                    \r\n            </ul>
                    \r\n</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="\&quot;top\&quot;"><strong>Size</strong></td>
                    <td>\r\n
                    <ul>\r\n
                        <li>Weight: 292 g</li>
                        \r\n
                        <li>Dimensions: 157 x 57 x 35 mm</li>
                        \r\n            </ul>
                        \r\n</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="\&quot;top\&quot;"><strong>Durability</strong></td>
                        <td>\r\n
                        <ul>\r\n
                            <li>High-resolution, active TFT colour display</li>
                            \r\n
                            <li>Up to 65,536 colours with 130x130 pixels</li>
                            \r\n
                            <li>Display texts in more than 20 languages</li>
                            \r\n
                            <li>Support for Latin, Arabic, Greek, Chinese and Korean</li>
                            \r\n            </ul>
                            \r\n</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="\&quot;top\&quot;"><strong>Keypad / Controls</strong></td>
                            <td>\r\n
                            <ul>\r\n
                                <li>2-sided user interface</li>
                                \r\n
                                <li>Alphanumeric keypad</li>
                                \r\n
                                <li>4 navigation keys, 3 selection keys</li>
                                \r\n
                                <li>HI/LO key for loudspeaker control</li>
                                \r\n
                                <li>Power-on key, volume keys, red function key, duty key, fast menu key, group selector, back key</li>
                                \r\n            </ul>
                                \r\n</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="\&quot;top\&quot;"><strong>GPS receiver</strong></td>
                                <td>\r\n
                                <ul>\r\n
                                    <li>Sensitivity &ndash;152 dBm</li>
                                    \r\n
                                    <li>Cold start accuracy (open sky)*<br />
                                    \r\n                5 metres (50% confidence level)<br />
                                    \r\n                10 meters (95% confidence level)<br />
                                    \r\n                * measured at &ndash;130 dBm<br />
                                    \r\n                HI/LO key for loudspeaker control</li>
                                    \r\n
                                    <li>GPS activity indicator</li>
                                    \r\n            </ul>
                                    \r\n</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Comment: Well, where are you stuck? Did you read in your file/data? Did you write some code to remove the content? Where did you get to? I guess it didn't work? So show us.

Comment: Similar thread, 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059091/how-to-remove-carriage-returns-from-output-of-string

Comment: $str=str_replace("\r\n","",$str);

Comment: how about `str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), "")`?

Comment: Actually ,above mentioned data is stored in my database.I have to format it by removing carriage and newlines before showing it on front end.str_replace is not working

Comment: string is not an ordinary string. there is some HTML embedded in it.Can you please tell me how to remove linefeeds and carriage from HTML code through PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in three way

1. Simply use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

   $str = preg_replace('~[\r\n]+~', '', $str);
2. You could get away with [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) on this one, although the code doesn't look as clean:

   $str = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $str);
3. you could do this with [trim()](https://www.php.net/trim)

Answer (score 1):

use the php [trim()](http://www.php.net/trim) function to clear leading/trailing charset:

```
" " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
"\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
"\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
"\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
"\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
"\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.
```

Comment: What about inner \r and \n ?

Comment: use [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) function. My suggestion was on the premise you were going through those lines by line.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like there is a lot **`\r\n.`**

So a simple **`str_replace`** will suffice.

```
<?php
$string=str_replace("\r\n","",$string);
```

Comment: string is not an ordinary string. there is some HTML embedded in it.Can you please tell me how to remove linefeeds and carriage from HTML code through PHP

Answer (score 0):

Uses str_replace function ?

[PHP faq](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)